# First Real Life - Working JS Script. How can I make it more efficient?

Tags: javascript

I have started to learn Javascript over the last few weeks. I have gone through most of the 'Head First Javascript Programming' book and it has been fantastic. I highly recommend it!

Anyways, I found a cool little project that I wanted to attempt to make a script for. After a few hours of learning, adding and bug squashing, I have a working script.

My question is (because I am new to JS), can I make this any simpler? Is there anything I have missed or gone a long way around with?

Advancing from here, how can I have the values in an object, and then look-up the object as per my current script? Is this possible or do I need an array for both 'Unit' and 'M3'?

My next step after that would be to have it connect to an XML or JSON document and retrieve the values from there and also to have error checking on each field.

Thanks!

Airflow Calculator:

Test Values:

Area: 150

Ceiling Height: 2.7

Adjustment Factor: 1

Unit: D095

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

//Air Changes Calculator

function init() {
    // Set the User Variables
    var unit = ["D095", "D125", "D160", "D195", "D230", "D255", "C125", "C160", "C205", "C240"];
    var m3 = [7500, 10000, 12500, 15000, 18000, 19500, 10000, 12500, 16000, 18500];

    var webPrint = document.getElementById("output");
    var reccommended = document.getElementById("reccommended");

    var floorArea = document.getElementById("floorarea").value;
    var ceilingHeight = document.getElementById("ceilingheight").value;
    var adjustmentFactor = document.getElementById("adjustment").value;
    var unitAir;

    var volume = floorArea * ceilingHeight;
    var adjustedVolume = volume * adjustmentFactor;
    var unitSelection = document.getElementById("model").value;


    for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
        if (unit[i] === unitSelection) {
            unitAir = m3[i];
        }
    }

    var calc = unitAir / adjustedVolume;

    webPrint.innerHTML = "For a " + floorArea + " m2 area, The "
    + unitSelection + " will provide " + Math.round(calc) + " air changes.";

// Function 2 - Get any unit that provides between 30 - 40 air changes for that area and adjustment factor

    var firstResult = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
        var suggestResult = m3[i] / adjustedVolume;

//      console.log(i);

        if ((suggestResult > 30 && suggestResult < 40 && firstResult == 0)) {
            var text;
            text = "We can also reccommend the " + unit[i] + " as it will give " + Math.round(suggestResult) + " air changes <br/>";
            document.getElementById("reccommended").innerHTML = text;
//          console.log("We are inside the TRUE");
            firstResult++
        } else if ((suggestResult > 30 && suggestResult < 40)) {
            var text;
            text += "We can also reccommend the " + unit[i] + " as it will give " + Math.round(suggestResult) + " air changes <br/>";
//          console.log("We are inside the FALSE");
        }
//console.log("This is the Result: " + firstResult);
    }
    document.getElementById("reccommended").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter Floor Area: <input type="text" name="floorarea" id="floorarea"></br></br>
Enter Ceiling Height: <input type="text" name="ceilingheight" id="ceilingheight"></br></br>
Enter Adjustment Factor (Min 1): <input type="text" name="adjustment" id="adjustment"></br></br>
Enter Unit Model: <input type="text" name="model" id="model"></br></br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="init()">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
<h2>Recommended Units:</h2>
    <p id="reccommended"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - It seems like this question doesn't belong here

Answer (score 1):

Agreed question does not belong here

But to help you out a bit

For a start - Split your html and Java script - move the Java Script into its own file and reference in.  I would also break your init() method up into smaller ones where appropriate.

You could start looking into Java script Name-spacing if you plan on having a larger app going forward to avoid confusion between method names.

Some thing like:

```
var app = 
{
    init:function()
    {
     // code goes here
    }
}
```

Then call the method like: app.init();